# Packard Bell Easynote TS1HR-120IT Notebook, is it compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

I've bought a Notebook Packard Bell EasyNote TS1HR-120IT and I want to install Linux (preferably Ubuntu  but I'm not sure if it is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at the specifications on the Packard-bell`s website, I see no problems in installing Ubuntu.  You may have some wireless issues, if you do you can check back here for the solution.  Welcome to Ubuntu :)